# How manage recurring subscription on mobile application

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, subscription, auto-renewing, in-app-subscription

I need to implement a renewable subscriptions in my mobile application, with different plans, duration and prices (like Netflix is doing), that is valid on mobile but also in my desktop app.
I read many threads and I understood that the only way to know if the subscription is correctly renewed is to check it from the mobile app: this is a problem for me because if I bought a subscription in my mobile app and I stop using it, but I'm still using the desktop application, at the end of the subscription I will not know if the subscription was renewed (because the user never opened the mobile app) and so I'll block the user for log-in in the desktop app.
I also read that it's not possibile to use Stripe or Paypal to manage the payment in mobile app, because the store will block the application that is not using a proprietary purchase system to sell not-physical goods or services.

So, the question is: is there a way to make a recurring subscription and know if it's currently active or not and the total payed without open the mobile app? If not, how can I manage a recurring subscription both in mobile and desktop apps? May be I'll need to create an external web page using a webview and then use Stripe or Paypal?

Thanks.
Matteo
Font:
[Renewalbe subscription on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015386/how-do-i-know-that-auto-renewalbe-subscription-is-cancelled-or-not)
[Implement Stripe in Xamarin](https://xamarinhelp.com/stripe-in-xamarin/)

**EDIT**
Our purpose is to manage subscriptions on desktop application but give the mobile user the possibility to buy a plan also on mobile.
Is possible to use a web view or default mobile browser to redirect the user to desktop web page and buy from here, without have any problem when publish app on apple and play store.

Comment: Why can't you get the subscription information using your desktop application? You should own the server, so that the database stored the user's information can be captured by yourself. I'm confused about your questions, please declare more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've update my question.

Comment: As you said above when we sell not-physical goods or services, we should use in-app purchase. But even though we use that, we also need to get subscriptions information from our own server. If your mobile app and desktop app use one server, the data can be shared between these two apps.